# KNeighborsRegressor as denoising algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, signal-processing, kaggle

On Kaggle I have found algorithms used for signals denoising. Such as Golay filters, spline functions, Autoregressive modelling or KNeighborsRegressor itself.

Link:
https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/denoising-algorithms

How exactly does it work as I cannot find any article explaining its use for signal denoising? What kind of algorithm is it? I would like to understand how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a supervised learning algorithm - that is the best answer,

normally the algorithm is first trained with known data and it tries to interpret a function that best represents that data such that a new point can be produced for a previously unseen input.

Put simply it will determine the point for a previously unseen value based on an average of the k nearest points for which it has previously seen, a better, more detailed answer can be found below:
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-knn-for-classification-and-regression-c1e8a6c955

**in the kaggle code:**

the time vector is:

```
df.index.values[:, np.newaxis]
```

and the signal vector is:

```
df.iloc[:, 0]
```

it appears the person in kaggle is using the data to first train the network - see below:

```
## define the KNN network
clf = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=100, weights='uniform')
## train the network 
clf.fit(df.index.values[:, np.newaxis], 
        df.iloc[:, 0])
```

giving him a function that represents the relationship between time and the signal value. With this he then passes the time vector back to the network to get it to reproduce the signal.

```
y_pred = clf.predict(df.index.values[:, np.newaxis])
```

this new signal will represent the model's best interpretation of the signal, as you can see from the the link I have posted above, you can adjust certain parameters which will result in a 'cleaner' signal but also could degrade the original signal

One thing to note is that using this method in the same way as that guy in kaggle means it would only work for that one signal since the input is **time** it cannot be used to interpret future values:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(df.index.values[:, np.newaxis] + 400000)
ax = pd.Series(df.iloc[:, 0]).plot(color='lightgray')
pd.Series(y_pred).plot(color='black', ax=ax, figsize=(12, 8))
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of noise is removed here?

Comment: I'd say High frequency, it is not really removing noise, but is really producing a representation of the original signal  as the chap on kaggle says: __learns to find the explainable variance and omit the incidental variance__ so it is removing incidental signals such as spikes but probably amplifies repeating low frequency signals - though I cannot say for certain without further investigation

Comment: I was asked whether I'm doing it globally or locally? What does it mean? What approach is presented in the article?

Comment: who asked? is this for an assignment?

Comment: it's one of my tasks, yes. I asked here to fully understand the topic

Comment: fine, with all respect, I am not going to answer provide you with a complete answer, however, it is not difficult to figure out if you read that link I provided above and you try to understand how the KNN works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230936/discussion-between-yras8-and-maxwell-redacted).